# How to bypass debounceTime in angular

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, debouncing, angular2-pipe

I have this text input with a `debounceTime` pipe, so that we don't hit the server too often while the user is typing the word:

```
this.keyUp$
  .pipe(debounceTime(500))
  .subscribe(data => this.onInputChanged.emit(data));
```

However, if the user hits Enter after entering the data, I would like to call `onInputChanged` immediately.

How can I bypass the `debounceTime` pipe depending on the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge your streams after `debounceTime`

```
this.keyUp$.pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        mergeWith(this.keyEnter$))
       .subscribe(data => this.onInputChanged.emit(data));
```

just keep in mind that after debounce time it will still emmit, so you have to add additiona filtering to ignore this pipeline if request is already in progress